# Reading/Parsing MS Project MPP java Android 5.0+?

Tags: java, android, apache, apache-poi, mpxj

Aloha to all.

There is an MPXJ.org project on Java to import MS project files of all versions, but the trouble is that for .mpp files higher than version 2000-2003 .mpp, for files higher than 2003 awt java lib is used awt.Color (getColor) that is not imported on Android and everything falls with

NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Color;

here the basic code

```
MPPReader reader = new MPPReader();
String path2file = context.getFilesDir() + "/" +SAMPLE21_MPPX;
ProjectFile projectFile = reader.read(path2file); //<-- falling here
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.bio.tj, PID: 13427

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Color;

at net.sf.mpxj.mpp.MPPUtility.getColor(MPPUtility.java:543) etc...

and this MPXJ also depends on the Apache POI, which is normally not importing to Android, too, do not connect, I used this Assembly: https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android

There is the solution for awt.Color, but here I don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is step by step solution.

- open [poi-on-android](https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android) project in android studio
- add to build.gradle (Module: poishadow)

// after this 2 lines

compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17'

compile 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'

// add this line with mpxj gradle

**compile group: 'net.sf.mpxj', name: 'mpxj', version: '7.2.1'**

- **compile project**, get file \poi-on-android-master\poishadow\build\libs\ **poishadow-all.jar**

it is all in one apache poi and mpxj, after that I took this file and imported in my project, seems working fine for the first run (tested on ms project 2010/2016 file), and onCreate in my project I added

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.InputFactoryImpl");
        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.OutputFactoryImpl");
        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory", "com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.EventFactoryImpl");
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the version of POI for Android that you provided a link to already solves this issue. Here is the definition of `java.awt.Color` provided by `poi-on-android`:

https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/blob/master/poishadow/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/java/awt/Color.java

Hopefully you'll either be able to use this source directly in your project, or pick up the class from the `poi-on-android` JAR itself.